# MVC 3 Action / Controller Attributes / Permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

To keep this example simple, my site has two controllers, UsersController & VenuesController, both of which have their own associated "admin permission".

So a user can have the "Users" admin permission and/or the "Venues" admin permission (these are bool fields on the users table in my db)

The user logs in and I have his/her permissions in session.

I want to decorate my controllers with a custom attribute to check the user has the correct permission to use the controller. I don't want to create a UserPermissionAttribute and a VenuePermissionAttribute, ideally I want a single attribute, that takes a bool property in and checks that it's true, so something like;

```
[CheckPermissionAttribute(_userSession.AdminPermissions.Users)]
public class UsersController : Controller
{

}
```

and

```
[CheckPermissionAttribute(_userSession.AdminPermissions.Venues)]
public class VenuesController : Controller
{

}
```

Is this possible to achieve, or should I be looking at PostSharp or something else to achieve the same results?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the built-in Role management feature?  You just assign a VenuesAdmin and UsersAdmin role to the users you want to have those permissions, then add a check using the standard Authorize attribute?

Comment: Yeah that is an option, probably the best option, as it stands the application doesn't use a membership provider, so I am exploring other ways of achieving the same thing?

Comment: How do you know who the user is then?

Answer (score 0):

you can create attribute with a parameter. Action filter parameters are properties of the action filter.

but it's better to create users roles and user the standart approach with [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The application does't use ASP.NET membership, I have a custom users table, where i store what permissions each use has. In the application I have these permissions in session. I want to have an attribute on the controller, where I can pass in a particular value from session i.e. if it's the users controller then I want to pass in the Session[HasUsersPermission], which is bool field (so either true of false). In my attribute I want to check if the value passed in is true, if so then they have access. This means on the venues controller i pass in Session[HasVenuePermission]

Comment: i realise attribute parameters need to be constant values, so i am looking for something else that will help me achieve this!